# What do 開眉粥 and 愁眉飯 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, food, phrase-meaning

I understand translations below on "寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁眉飯". I know 粥 means congee and 飯 rice or meal. I tried look up [愁眉 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%84%81%E7%9C%89) but meaning doesn't sense.

> 1. [knitted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knitted) [brows](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brow)

[宁食开眉粥 不食愁眉饭什么意思_百度知道](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/341395827.html)

> [liumengdie17](https://zhidao.baidu.com/usercenter?uid=53074069236f25705e798c0e&role=ugc)   2011-11-12

> 就是说。宁可物质上一般，但是生活心态开心，而不要为了更高的物质。把自己搞的很累。最后就是人在天堂，钱在银行

[「寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁買飯」的大意 | Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060224000013KK11689)

> 旺來Lv 5
> 1 decade ago

> ~比喻寧願心情開朗的過窮日子，不願過充滿煩惱的富裕生活。強調精神生活的重要性。例如：王先生說對我說：「現在的工作雖然薪水少了點，但是我做得心安理得，人家說『寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁眉飯』，以前那種事，我再也不做了。

[What is "宁喝开眉粥 莫吃秋眉饭” Is it idiom and what is its meaning? | HiNative](https://hinative.com/zh-CN/questions/88384)

> “宁喝开眉粥，不吃愁眉饭”是一句谚语，意为宁可开心愉快地喝稀饭，也不要伤心愤怒地吃大餐。这句谚语告诉人们，快乐是人生的必需品，人要学会经营快乐。the most important thing is happy

Comment: Hint: 粥 (*congee*) is watered-down rice, a metaphor of poverty. The phrase pairs happiness  (or rather 開眉, non-frowns) with poverty and a frown face (*knitted brows*) with a materially fuller life (飯, non-watered-down rice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

開眉 implies 眉開眼笑 (happy expression)

[image]

愁眉 implies 愁眉苦臉 (sad expression)

[image]

One cup of raw rice can only make two bowls of cooked rice (飯)

One cup of raw rice can make up to eight bowls of congee (粥)

粥 is watered-down 飯

Poor families often only have enough raw rice to make congee for every member to have a full bowl of staple food

"寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁眉飯" literally means "rather eat congee with a smiling face than eat cooked rice with a frowning face". It is a metaphor for "Better  live a poor but happy life than a rich but unhappy one"

(diminish the importance of material wealth)

You can use this expression to describe a situation like someone rather take a low paying job than earning money with immoral acts

Side note:

Cantonese expression: 有粥食粥，有飯食飯 = through thick and thin

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of the infamous quote "宁坐宝马车里哭，不坐自行车上笑" 

Comment: I'd rather 宁坐自行车上笑 ，不坐宝马车里哭.

Comment: There are bicycle costs as much as a car

Comment: @Tang Ho. So your graphic design talent is put to good use here. :-)  BTW, in my view there is a subtle difference between 有粥食粥，有飯食飯 and 寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁眉飯. The former means one has no choice but be poor and had to make the best of eating 粥 only; whereas the latter implies that given a choice of being poor but happy or rich but sad, the former is chosen.

Comment: 有粥食粥，有飯食飯 and 寧吃開眉粥，不吃愁眉飯 are two different expressions

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to point out that the "difference" lies in one having a choice of being rich or poor and none for the other.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, The rice is more resistant to hunger than congee. In Cantonese, "eating rice or congee" is often used to describe the outcome of a thing. "开眉" means "happy" and "愁眉" means "unhappy". So this sentence can be interpreted as: Do you want to be happy to do what you want to do, or unhappy to do what you don't want to do?